# Php mail() function not doing what it should

Tags: php, email

I made a 000webhost website and I made a php form that basically evaluates whatever code you put in there. I’m trying a basic mail function to myself (iCloud account) but it always returns false. Here’s the code:

```
Mail(‘myEmail@icloud.com’, ‘subject’, ‘body’, ‘From: <someEmail@somewhere.com>’);
```

Comment: Fix your quotes. You can't use curly quotes in PHP code.

Comment: Check your mail configuration in php.ini, make sure it's correct.

Comment: Okay, I’ll fix the quotes. I’ve checked the php.ini file, it seems good, and I’ll make sure to check out that link.